# Replace $, add ₹+0 from str in Python

Tags: python

Expecting:
convert string from "Hello $500 $700" to "Hello ₹5000 ₹7000"

I have tried a lot and currently using this code

```
import re


def remove_dollar_add_rupee(line):
    if "$" in line:
        pattern = re.compile(
            r"(?:[£$]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)(?: euros?)?)")
        for match in pattern.finditer(line):
            captured = match.group()
            print(captured)
            new_captured = captured.replace("$", "₹")+"0"
            final_output = line.replace(captured, new_captured)
            return final_output
    else:
        return line


full_line = "Hello $500 $700"

print(remove_dollar_add_rupee(full_line))
```

This code replace first $500, not $700.
Any way to fix this? or completely change this function to some better solution?

Comment: You first check if "$" is in the line, but your regex allows for all sorts of other variants, too, like pounds or euros (incl. in words). Also, the regex allows for decimal places, but in this case, just appending a `0` _after_ the decimal point clearly won't work. Do you _only_ want to replace whole `$` and got that regex from somewhere else, or do you actually want to handle all those cases?

Comment: why dont you just use `re.sub()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do as follows:

```
" ".join(["₹" + substr[1:] + "0" if substr[0] == "$" else substr for substr in str.split()])
```

```
Input: str = "Hello $500 $700 $"
Output: 'Hello ₹5000 ₹7000 ₹0'
```

This solution only works for a string with `<space>$<number><space>` patterns.

Comment: You're a gem. Thank you.

Comment: Could also use `re.sub`: `re.sub(r"\$(\d+)", lambda m: f"₹{m.group(1)}0", line)`

Answer (score 2):

You are returning inside the loop, which means 2nd iteration will never happen.
Edit your line and return it at the end.

```
def remove_dollar_add_rupee(line):
    if "$" in line:
        pattern = re.compile(
            r"(?:[£$]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)(?: euros?)?)")
        for match in pattern.finditer(line):
            captured = match.group()
            print(captured)
            new_captured = captured.replace("$", "₹")+"0"
            line = line.replace(captured, new_captured)
    return line
```

Comment: oops, thank you for clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

Dude you are using `Python`, a language created by god himself.

Do not overcomplicate things:

```
line = "Hello $700 $500"
line = line.replace("$", "₹")
matches = re.findall(r"₹\d+", line) # Added ₹ to Match only with rupee symbol.
for match in matches:
    line = line.replace(match, match + "0")
print(line)
```

Output:

```
Hello ₹7000 ₹5000
```

Edit: Sorry didn't read the question title carefully.

Comment: This does not achieve what OP wants.

Comment: Still does not work if line contains other numbers.

Comment: regex could me modifed for that, see my updated answer.